# How can I remove EPEL 7.0 repo from CentOS 6.5 install?

Tags: centos, epel

While trying to update PHP 5.4 to 7.2, libcurl package update showing epel 7 is installed. How can I remove this from centos 6 and install epel 6.8?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. To remove current `epel-release` use:

   ```
   yum remove epel-release
   yum update
   ```

   or

   ```
   rm /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo
   yum update
   ```
2. To install `epel-release 6.8` use:

   ```
   yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
   yum update
   ```

   or

   ```
   yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
   yum update
   ```